# remix not showing me any error but output 0

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

    contract Bank{
    uint private value;

    function Bank(uint amount){
        value = amount;
    }
    function deposit(uint amount){
        value += amount;
    }
    function withdraw(uint amount){
        value -= amount;
    }
    function balance() returns (uint){
        return value;
    }
}

contract MyFirstContract is Bank(10)
{
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName){
        name = newName;
    }
    function getName()returns(string){
        return name;
    }
    function setAge(uint newAge){
        age = newAge;
    }
    function getAge() returns (uint) {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I am executing my contract it compiles successfully. I have passed default value inside my bank constructor and then i get the balance but it is showing me blank.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are setting the visibility of "value" to `private`

As per the [doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) :

> private:
>   Private functions and state variables are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.

I tried in remix by changing the `visibility` to public and I got the correct value .

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Bank {

    uint public value;

    function Bank(uint amount){
        value = amount;
    }
    function deposit(uint amount){
        value += amount;
    }
    function withdraw(uint amount){
        value -= amount;
    }
    function balance() returns (uint){
        return value;
    }
}

contract MyFirstContract is Bank(10) {

    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName){
        name = newName;
    }
    function getName()returns(string){
        return name;
    }
    function setAge(uint newAge){
        age = newAge;
    }
    function getAge() returns (uint) {
        return age;
    }
}
```

And while creating an instance of `MyFirstContract` (in remix using as well javascript vm) it gives me the result "10" when I'm calling `balance` .

```
 status     0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
 to     browser/ballot.sol:MyFirstContract.balance() 0xef55bfac4228981e850936aaf042951f7b146e41
 gas    3000000 gas
 transaction cost   21798 gas 
 execution cost     526 gas 
 hash   0xaf38d98f04f66d38034ae2b88922eaa00c2f487610fa00f32c17e1fbc6e0cd7f
 input  0xb69ef8a8
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "uint256: 10"
}
 logs   []
 value  0 wei
```

Comment: Could you share the exact code you used to get this working? When I use Remix and just change the declaration of `value` to `uint public value`, it still seems to hold the value `0` (according to calls to `balance()` as well as inspecting via the public getter for `value`). Note that I'm using the JavaScript VM.

Comment: Sure I've updated my post .

Comment: I don't think that the visibility of `amount` has anything to do with this working; see my answer. For me, `balance()` returns the correct value even when `amount` is `private` (as long as the right contract is deployed).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're deploying the right contract.

Your code defines two contracts: `Bank` and `MyFirtContract`. I find that Remix defaults to `Bank` (perhaps based on the order the contracts are defined, or perhaps simply alphabetically?), and deploying `Bank` of course results in a `value` of `0`. When I deploy `MyFirstContract` with the exact code in your post, I find that `balance()` returns `10` as expected.

(You can choose which contract to deploy via a dropdown in the "run" tab.)